# Comparison principle for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, differential-geometry, continuity, lyapunov-functions

I am trying to solve example 3.8 in the book Nonlinear systems by Hassan Khalil and I have been unable to figure out how they got the answer for $\frac{\mathrm dv(t)}{\mathrm dt}$ as $-2x^2(t)$. I will be grateful if someone can please explain it to me. I have attached a screenshot of the problem.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

The term $-2x^4(t)$ is negative(non-positive actually) , so $-2x^2(t) - 2x^4(t) \leq -2x^2(t)$ since adding a negative quantity always reduces what you have first. Since $v(t) = x^2(t)$, it follows that $\dot{v}(t) \leq -2v(t)$, and by the comparison lemma for linear systems, $v(t) \leq u(t)$ and the bound on $x(t)$ follows.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am still trying to understand the concept presented. It is still confusing..

Comment: @Tee If you have more specific questions, you can ask them here! Make sure you follow the guidelines. It is confusing at first, but that's non-linearity for you : when I did this material I was also in confusion over the behavior of this field, because it is off the intuitive radar. But keep going at it : if you liked this answer and would like more input, then call me to your questions with the @ sign. For starters, you can tell me what you find "still confusing" in this example.

Comment: By computation (i.e. inserting values for x), I know that  $-2x^2-2x^4≤-2x^2$. The same is also true for  $- 2x^2-2x^4≤-2x^4$  So my question is, why did they pick $ 2x^2$  instead of $2x^4$.Understanding the concept will help me to solve any other question.  Thank you for your help. @Teresa Lisbon

Comment: @Tee The inequality you mention is correct. However, see the impact once you put back $v$  in $\dot{v}(t) \leq 2x^4(t)$ : you get $\dot{v}(t) \leq 2v^2(t)$, which is a *non-linear* inequation. No comparison principle is known for this equation at the point of your study , so you won't be able to proceed beyond this point. Instead, the other inequality produces a *linear* inequation, for which a comparison principle is known and is applicable. That is why this particular inequality was used and not the one you mention : but if you are pointing it out and thinking about it, well done!

Comment: It is clear now. Thank you for your help. @Teresa Lisbon

Comment: @Tee You are welcome!